# Sunlight on an object

Tags: optics, satellites, solar-sails

I'm not entirely sure how I should be phrasing this question, but it's part of a project I'm working on. It's all about finding reflectivity by way of a telescope.

We figured the first way to proceed was to figure out the amount of sunlight that would hit this object in the first place. We know the solar constant, the size of the object and we can assume it's at LEO(low earth orbit).

Without giving away too much, how do you go about figuring out the amount of sunlight that hits this object? Is there some formula for this? or maybe a procedure of steps I should start working on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At the distance of the earth, [solar radiation](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/solar-radiation-in-space) amounts to about $1.37kW/m^2$. Knowing the size of your object and the angle at which it is presented to the sun, lets you work out the amount of power received. As the sun is approximately 150,000,000 km away, the exact position of the craft, whether it be at LEO, GSO or even lunar orbit, will make very little difference.

This is total power. If you are interested in visible light only, the power will be lower.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It makes a lot of sense. I think we're only referring to visible sunlight. Do you know how I would go about setting this up mathematically? Or possibly a source i can start looking into?

Comment: @TheAgile, you should check out Planck's Law (blackbody radiation). To get the relative radiation in the visible spectrum, simply integrate this equation in the visible spectrum (say, if you use the one that is a function of wavelength, integrate from 400nm to 700nm), and normalize. Of course, use Mathematica or any software. If I recall correctly it is at least greater than .9, but don't quote me on that :)

Comment: To set it up mathematically, look at the link I gave, they give some formulas. However, you may need a lot more detail: spectrum of interest, material affected, angle of it to the sun, is the object rotation relative to the sun, etc.